# My picture can't fill the tab

Tags: android

I develop an app like below,In the mainActivity,when I try to add an image the TAB1,the picuture can't fill full of the tab,it has a border lost.

[image: activity picutre]

The yellow part is the TAB1,I need yellow color fill with the TAB1.any help will be appreciated :),thanks

### EDIT:

I update my key code

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity implements OnTabChangeListener{

    private TabSpec ts1,ts2,ts3;//declare three page
    private TabHost tableHost;

    @override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreat(savedInstanceState);
    tableHost=this.getTabHost();
    LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layou.activity_main,tableHost.getTabContentView());
    ts1=tableHost.newTabSpec("Tabone");
    ts1.setIndicator("TAB1",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.read2));
    ts1.setContent(R.id.btn);
    ts2=tableHost.newTabSpec("Tabtwo");
    ts2.setIndicator("TAB2");
    ts2.setContent(R.id.et);
    ts3=tableHost.newTabSpec("Tabthree");
    ts3.setIndicator("TAB3");
    ts3.setContent(R.id.mylayout);
    tableHost.addTab(ts1);
    tableHost.addTab(ts2);
    tableHost.addTab(ts3);
    tableHost.setOntabChangedListener(this);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try Your app on emulator or on a real device? If you had set "match_parent" to your Layout, it should work. But I got a similar problem with my Samsung Galaxy S3, it could be that is a hardware error, not your fail.

### EDIT

Ok, so if You just use Java-Code without xml definition, maybe you should set the layout-params for the tabhost. I don´t realy know, just an assumption.

```
    tableHost = new TabHost(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    tableHost.setLayoutParams(params);
```

But there are many LayoutParams, don´t know if LinearLayout.LayoutParams are the right one for you. If it doesn´t work, you have to try some other LayoutParams.

Comment: not the hardware error,I have update my code up ,could you help me please

Comment: I have tried your answer but nothing change ,after i put linearlayout in ,the app close automatic.

Comment: If app closes directly means, that are the wrong LayoutParams. Please read Developer Guide to choose the right ones at: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html . TabHost extends FrameLayout, so maybe Your need FrameLayout.LayoutParams

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
In this coding you should use two images that one is actual image and another one  that's you added yellow color background with your image.
```

### tab1_mainxml  :   //This xml file should store into drawable folder

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected, use grey -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab1icon"

      android:state_selected="true"/>
    <!-- When not selected, use white-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab1icon2" />
    </selector>
```

### Tab host Activity:

```
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost
            .newTabSpec("Tab1")

            .setIndicator("Tab1", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab1_mainxml))
            .setContent(intent));
```

Comment: I just set in java files ,I have updated my code on,could you help me please?

Comment: I have tried your answer,but it doesn't work ,can you help me ?

Comment: What was the problem occur from this coding? Here it's working well. While i selected tab the view goes with yellow background.Are used try with two images?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html) for creating tab icons. You'll get all needed resources for "native tab icon" look.